# Apache Axis2/Rampart + Maven

Tags: java, web-services, maven, apache-axis, rampart

we've got an **maven integration test** that uses **axis2 client** with **rampart**. **rampart.mar** is specified as a dependency in the pom, however maven is not including it in the classpath. the mar is required for axis to load the rampart module.

Does anyone have a solution?

pom.xml snippet:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
            <artifactId>rampart</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <type>mar</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could share relevant pom snippet?

Comment: Can you pls look in to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979339/exception-while-running-the-client-request-to-rampart-samples-in-tomcat-the-sec) question

Answer (score 1):

I've used axis2-1.6.0 with rampart-1.6.0 with the following pom extract:

```
<!-- axis2/axiom: dependencies -->
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
      <version>${axis2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>  
   <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>  
   <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>  
   <version>${axis2.version}</version>  
</dependency>
<dependency>  
   <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>  
   <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>  
   <version>${axis2.version}</version>  
</dependency>         
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-codegen</artifactId>
    <version>${axis2.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>   

<!-- axis2-rampart: dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
    <artifactId>rampart-core</artifactId>
    <version>${axis2.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- slf4j: dependencies -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
  <!-- 
  <scope>runtime</scope>
  -->
</dependency> 
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- log4j: dependencies -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>${log4j.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<properties>
<slf4j.version>1.6.3</slf4j.version>  
    <log4j.version>1.2.15</log4j.version>
    <axis2.version>1.6.0</axis2.version>
    <rampart.version>1.6.0</rampart.version>
</properties>
```

however, in services usage as client or server you need to specify the axis2-repository runtime location.

```
        // get Modulrepository
        ConfigurationContext ctx = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem( AXIS2_REPOSITORY, null);

        // create new Stub
        Stub stub = createStub(ctx);

        // configure and engage Rampart
        ServiceClient client = stub._getServiceClient();


        Options options = client.getOptions();     

        // modify charset
        options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.Constants.Configuration.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING, charsetEncoding );


        // // modify endpoint
        // options.setTo(new org.apache.axis2.addressing.EndpointReference( ENDPOINT_LOCATION ));

        // modify policies
        Policy policy = loadPolicy(POLICY_FILE);
        client.getAxisService().getPolicySubject().attachPolicy(policy);
```

Actually I've got some problems with axis2-1.6.1 because of neethy policy validation update

Comment: Can you pls look in to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979339/exception-while-running-the-client-request-to-rampart-samples-in-tomcat-the-sec) question

Answer (score 0):

keep and eye on an eventual stackoverflow error.

http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html jcl-over-slf4j.jar should not be confused with slf4j-jcl.jar

Comment: Can you pls look in to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979339/exception-while-running-the-client-request-to-rampart-samples-in-tomcat-the-sec) question